# Whenever i run the code my default case always runs with the other cases (C++)

Tags: c++, switch-statement, getch

I have used the Break too at the end of every case but it's not breaking it. I think `_getch()` is taking two inputs at a time or it always has some garbage data at the start of each loop.

Here's the code generating this issue.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        c = 0;

        switch ((c = _getch())) {
        case 72:
            cout << endl << "Up" << endl;//key up
            break;
        case 80:
            cout << endl << "Down" << endl;   // key down
            break;
        case 75:
            cout << endl << "Left" << endl;  // key left
            break;
        case 77:
            cout << endl << "Right" << endl;  // key right
            break;
        default:
            cout << endl << "null" << endl;  // not arrow
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: [Here my output]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the arrow keys two values are generated. The first one is `0xE0` to indicate that the following one is something out of the ordinary.

Your code fixed:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    do {
        c = _getch();
        if (c == 0xE0)
            c = _getch();

        switch (c) {
        case 72:
            std::cout << "Up\n";
            break;
        case 80:
            std::cout << "Down\n";
            break;
        case 75:
            std::cout << "Left\n";
            break;
        case 77:
            std::cout << "Right\n";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "null\n";
            break;
        }

    } while (c != 0x1B /* esc */);
}
```